# How to reorder the index for mic on new Raspbian Jessie for PocketSphinx?

Tags: raspbian-jessie, alsa

I am attaching a mic to my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B (Jessie) and using it for my PocketSphinx implementation.

I see this in the system:

```
$cat /proc/asound/cards                                                                                                                            
0 [ALSA           ]: bcm2835 - bcm2835 ALSA                                                                                                                   
                     bcm2835 ALSA                                                                                                                             
1 [Mic            ]: USB-Audio - Samson Meteor Mic                                                                                                            
                     Samson Technologies Samson Meteor Mic at usb-3f980000.usb-1.2, full speed
```

According to PocketSphinx documentation, I need to move the mic to index 0. In Wheezy, you alter the file located at **/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf** with the following:

```
options snd-usb-audio index=0
```

However, in Jessie, the ALSA configuration system has changed. There is no alsa-base.conf anymore and it is replaced by **/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf**.

The format in the new conf file doesn't seem to be compatible with the old format.

Help!

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround. Instead of re-ordering the index for the mic card, I can change the default mic card with this:

```
$sudo vi ~/.asoundrc

pcm.usb
{
    type hw
    card Mic
}

pcm.internal
{
    type hw
    card ALSA
}

pcm.!default
{
    type asym
    playback.pcm
    {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "internal"
    }
    capture.pcm
    {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "usb"
    }
}

ctl.!default
{
    type asym
    playback.pcm
    {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "internal"
    }
    capture.pcm
    {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "usb"
    }
}
```

Make sure to change "Mic" to whatever card name is recognized by your system by doing "cat /proc/asound/cards".

Comment: I got the following error:
ALSA lib dlmisc.c:252:(snd1_dlobj_cache_get) Cannot open shared library /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_asym.so