# Pi doesn't detect microphone but detects usb device

Tags: usb, audio

I had my Raspberry Pi configured to work with a USB microphone (C-Media microphone USB). 
I had made the following changes

For `/lib/modprobe.d/aliases` I update the following lines

```
options snd-usb-audio index=0 
options snd_bcm2835 index=1
```

My asoundrc file has the following

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}
```

My microphone shows up as a USB device when I run `lsusb` but doesn't show up when I try a `arecord -l`

I have attached a copy of the dmesg log which shows an error. Any suggestions on fixing this issue are welcome.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Similar post : https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/46799/usb-microphone-raspberry-pi?rq=1

Comment: @CoderMike In that post, the person is unable to hear anything but in this case the microphone doesn't show up as a hardware capture device

Comment: Error -16 is EBUSY so it seems like you're on the right track. That `][1]][1]` in your asoundrc is a typo, right? Because if I include that in `/etc/asound.conf`, arecord naturally says parse error. I don't have your particular mic, but running `sudo modprobe snd_bcm2835 index=1` results in unknown parameter 'index' so perhaps what you want to try instead is: `sudo modprobe -r snd_bcm2835; sudo modprobe snd-usb-audio index=0`. (Once this is better troubleshooted/easily reproducible at runtime, then we can loop back and try to get it consistent at boot time e.g. /lib/modprobe.d)

Comment: @jdonald Did you want me to run these lines of code when I face this issue?
`sudo modprobe -r snd_bcm2835; `
`sudo modprobe snd-usb-audio index=0`

Do you have any suggestions on how I can force this error on bootup?

Comment: It would be greatly appreciated if you could post the output of `lsusb` in your question, ideally, in text .... images suck, because they cannot be indexed (for search) and our blind friends cannot help you.

Comment: It may be a race condition so hard to force on bootup. I'm suggesting you remove the bootup configuration (`sudo rm /lib/modprobe.d/aliases`) and try to reproduce the error several times at runtime, even try reordering the load of snd_bcm2835. Re-test by unloading each module: `sudo modprobe -r snd-usb-audio; sudo modprobe -r snd_bcm2835` and then loading again (`-r` means remove, while modprobe normally loads a module if not loaded already). In either situation you can run `lsmod` to see if other snd modules are loaded and potentially conflicting (and check dmesg) then provide more info.

Comment: What is the output if you type:  `cat /proc/asound/cards` ?